# GLM Residual in Python statsmodel

Tags: python, r, regression, linear-regression

How to generate residuals for all 303 observations in Python:

```
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import OLSInfluence
OLSInfluence(resid)
```

or

```
res.resid()
```

I am trying to generate residual similar to what we generate in R using:

```
res$resid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

statsmodels does not have a default `resid` for `GLM`, but it has the following

resid_anscombe Anscombe residuals.

resid_anscombe_scaled Scaled Anscombe residuals.

resid_anscombe_unscaled Unscaled Anscombe residuals.

resid_deviance Deviance residuals.

resid_pearson Pearson residuals.

resid_response Response residuals.

resid_working Working residuals.

https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLMResults.html

The residual `y - E(y|x)` are the response residuals `resid_response`

Those residuals are available as attributes of the results instance that is returned by the `fit` method.

Comment: Thanks Josef. If, `Result=smf.glm('y~x', data=x)` and `Result=Result.fit()`.  How do i use resid_response?

Comment: clearer is to distinguish model and results instances: `model=smf.glm('y~x', data=x)`, `results=model.fit()`, `resid=results.resid_response`

Comment: Inplace of `data=x`, even if I put `data=y` or some other data, I still get the same result. So, what is data here? Documentation is not very clear.

Comment: Data is a pandas DataFrame with column names that are used in formula, e.g. "y" and "x" in your example. (It could also be a dict or other structure with access by name.) There are many examples for this floating around. https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/formulas.html )

Comment: Hi Josef, Is there a way to get response type residual for RLM as well? `results.resid` does not tie back with RLM residual from R